# Is vector based distance between a point and a line differentiable?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

We calculate the shortest distance between a point and a straight line. Consider a line given by the points $$r=a+b.t$$
The point from which the distance to the line will be calculates is $$x$$
The l1 distance between the given line and the given point is $$l1(||x-r||)$$

> We will be minimizing this distance cost function l1, but first I need to know whether it is differentiable? Need some explanation.

Comment: Where is $f$ coming from and what is its meaning in this context. What do you mean by "vector-based" ? Please given an example of a pertinent $f$

Comment: @Jean Marie, I hope the question is now clear.

Comment: You mean the 1-norm that is usually written $\|x-r\|_1$ written in Latex `$\|x-r\|_1$`. Answer: no, it isn't differentiable.

Comment: Can you please explain a little how it is not differentiable? and what is meant by differentiable functions?

Comment: More precisely, if the equation of line L is $ux+vy+w=0$, the $\ell_1$ distance from $(x,y)$ to L can be computed as $\min\left(\left|\frac{1}{v}(ux+vy+w)\right|,\left|\frac{1}{u}(ux+vy+w)\right|\right)$.